# Time Height Cross Section in GrADS

Tags: bash, scripting, grads

I am looking to generate a time-height cross section in GrADS, but need some help rolling in the right direction. My goal is to generate data from a specific lat/lon point I'll specify in the GrADS script. I intend to pull the grib2 files from NOMADS, specifically the 4km NAM & GFS flavor.

I am not sure how to portray the vertical cross section data across a function of time as opposed to a function of elevation in the x-axis. I've been using the link below as a mainframe for my script, but need to work around the elevation dependency.

http://gradsaddict.blogspot.com/2013/05/tutorial-vertical-cross-section-with.html

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

In general, what you are looking for is a Hovmoller-plot.

Have a look at this:

http://gradsaddict.blogspot.jp/2013/05/tutorial-grads-hovmoller-diagram.html

and this:

https://nelson.wisc.edu/ccr/resources/grads/maps-and-graphs.php

In any case, it would be better if you can provide a sample data here (the smallest possible)